# Android file copying using Runtime.exec() not working

Tags: java, android, local-storage, android-sdcard

I am trying to copy a file 'project.jpg' from my /sdcard to /sdcard/temp/ folder, but for some reason , the file isn't getting copied. I am testing using a virtual device and have transferred the file 'project.jpg' via the adb shell. The function used to copy the file is,

```
public void $copyFile()
{
    try
    {
        cpSrc = escapePath(this.cpSrc);
        cpDest = escapePath(this.cpDest);
        Log.d("$copyFile()","cpSrc = "+cpSrc);
        Log.d("$copyFile()","cpDest = "+cpDest);
        String destination = getFilename(cpDest,extractFilename(cpSrc));
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dd in="+cpSrc+" of="+destination);
        Log.d("$copyFile()","executed command : 'dd in="+cpSrc+" of="+destination+"'");
        displayToast("File Copied Sucessfully.");
        clearAllModes();
        return;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        displayToast("$copyFile Error : "+e);
        this.clearCopyBuffer();
        clearAllModes();
    }
}
```

where escapePath() is used to escape space characters(if any) in the given paths. I got the debug Logs as follows,

```
cpSrc = /sdcard/project.jpg
cpDest = /sdcard/temp
executed command : 'dd in=/sdcard/project.jpg of=/sdcard/temp/project.jpg
```

Could anyone point the error in the code,
BTW suggestions for other ways of coping files/folders ? it would be helpful as i am trying my hand at a file manager.

Comment: Have you added the correct user-permissions in the manifest file? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` and also `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

Comment: I have added the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission but not the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE , I will try adding the read permission and report in a short while.

Comment: @Pierre: tried adding the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, still unable to copy file.

Comment: @cyberPheonix if your application holds the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, the documentation says that `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is automatically granted then. but are you sure the folder /sdcard/temp/ exists? else `dd` cannot open the file for writing

Comment: @MalteSchmitz: yes I am sure , because I created them using adb shell and when i run the ls command, it shows all the files/folders.

Comment: Finally found it, I have actually used dd in='' instead of dd if='' , such a silly mistake, anyway thanks for the help guys.

Comment: @cyberPheonix never mind, and have fun

Comment: Since `dd` is not guaranteed to exist, I would recommend copying using Java code, not shelling out to a potentially-nonexistent command.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thanks for the suggestion, will change my code such that , if dd command does not exist then i will copy using Java code.

Comment: @cyberPheonix Happy to see you got it.